# Copy vector of vectors in copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy, copy-constructor, stdvector

I want to copy a vector of vectors of type int inside a copy constructor.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> * > * bar;
```

This does not work:

```
Foo(const Foo& rhs)
: bar(new std::vector<std::vector<int> * >(rhs.vec->size())) {

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rhs.bar->size(); i++) {
        bar->push_back(new std::vector<int>());
        for (size_t j = 0; j < (*rhs.bar)[i]->size(); j++) {
            bar->back()->push_back((*rhs.bar)[i]->at(j));
        }
    }
}
```

I also thought if I could use something with `swap` and `back()` but I am not sure if this is working out.

Could somebody show me a proper way to make a copy? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: If you really had a "vector of vectors of type int", you wouldn't need to do anything special in the copy constructor.  Why are you using all those pointers?

Comment: Are the pointers in `std::vector<std::vector<int> * > * bar;` really necessary?

Comment: This is awful code. Don't say `*` in C++ unless you mean "multiplication".

Comment: What's with all the pointers? A vector of vectors of ints is not the same as a vector of pointers to vectors to ints.

Comment: I believe mixing pointers and STL containers is a bad habit. It unnecessarily makes your code more complex and pave the way for subtle bugs. I am not even talking about initializing those std::vector<> arrays.

Comment: OK, this is enough comments for me to reconsider that! Sorry it is late over here!

Comment: On a side note: If you really ever need to use pointers, consider using std::shared_ptr / std::unique_ptr. If you want to copy the pointer, but not the object pointed at, you obviously need std::shared_ptr.

Comment: This is no question, I do that. It is just a first design. When things get worked out I always try to use shared_ptr!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your actual storage type is `int`, I can think of no good reason to use any pointers in this case.  Change your member variable to not use pointers, and simply let the copy constructors of the `vector` objects do the work for you.

```
class T
{
public:
   T() {};

   // For this class, the copy constructor isn't even necessary!

private:
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> v_;
};
```

Comment: Yes, I know, using no pointers make the copy constructor (and assignment operator) redundant. I guess I ran into troubles with the storage above. Thanks for the wake up clap!

Answer (score 7):

If you have what you *said*, a vector of vectors of ints, and not what you *showed* (a pointer to a vector of pointers to vectors to ints), then the object can do it already. You just use its copy constructor or assignment operator:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > vec;
std::vector<std::vector<int> > copy_of_vec = vec;
```

Yes, it's really that simple once you get rid of all the pointers.